# Rewrite a csv file by rearranging columns and rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file (let's call it input.csv) that looks like this:

```
ID; Text_1; Points_1; Text_2; Points_2
1; "Hello world one"; 33; "Hello world two"; 90
2, "Goodbye world one"; 44; "Goodbye world two";100
```

I want to create another csv file (let's call it output.csv) that rearranges the columns like this:

```
 ID; Field; Sent; Points;
 1; Text_1;"Hello world one"; 33
 1; Text_2;"Hello world two"; 90
 2; Text_1;"Goodbye world one"; 44
 2; Text_2;"Goodbye world two"; 100
```

It does not seem as easy as a priori I thought. I wonder if there is a way to directly transcribe the file. Thanks in advance.

I've tried this with some help, but I have difficulties to read and copy the columns and rows in the order I said.

```
with open("results.csv", "r") as text:
    reader = csv.DictReader(text, delimiter=";")

rows = [l.split(";") for l in text.split("\n")]
del filas[0] 

newlist = list()
for l in filas:
  newlist.append([l[0], 'Texto_1', l[2]])
  newlist.append([l[0], 'Texto_2', l[4]])
```

Comment: Did you try writing some code so far?

Comment: I edited the question to copy a piece of non coherent code that I have so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read each row and write out two rows with the appropriate fields:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as infile:
    with open('output.csv','w',newline='') as outfile:
        r = csv.reader(infile,delimiter=';')
        w = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=';')
        next(r) # skip the original header
        w.writerow('ID Field Sent Points'.split())
        for id,t1,p1,t2,p2 in r:
            w.writerows([[id,'Text_1',t1,p1],
                         [id,'Text_2',t2,p2]])
```

Output:

```
ID;Field;Sent;Points
1;Text_1;Hello world one;33
1;Text_2;Hello world two;90
2;Text_1;Goodbye world one;44
2;Text_2;Goodbye world two;100
```

Note: Quotes are unnecessary for the .csv module unless the field contains a delimiter.  There are other options to `csv.writer` for quoting if you want them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Mark. The problem is that I'm working with large files, massives amounts of data. Thus, I'd not be able to write row by row the text in writerows. I mean, imagine that you have 1000 rows, for example.

Comment: @pyring That was not specified in the question, but 1000 rows is not many.  If you have massive amounts of data, you should be using a database not a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Tolonen. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def get_data()
   with open('filename.csv') as f:
      data = [i.strip('\n').split('; ') for i in f]
      header = data[0]
      for i, a in enumerate(data):
          yield [data[0], header[1], data[1], data[2]]
          yield [data[0], header[3], data[3], data[4]]

final_data = ['; '.join(i) for i in get_data()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code won't provide you what you are exactly looking for but I believe it will help you to reorganize the columns in a `csv` file.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Text_1', 'Text_2', 'Points_1', 'Points_2']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # reorder the header first
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        # writes the reordered rows to the new file
        writer.writerow(row)
```

For the following input:

```
ID, Text_1, Points_1, Text_2, Points_2
1, "Hello world one", 33, "Hello world two", 90
2, "Goodbye world one", 44, "Goodbye world two",100
```

The above program will output:

```
ID, Text_1, Text_2, Points_1, Points_2
1, "Hello world one", "Hello world two", 33, 90
2, "Goodbye world one", "Goodbye world two", 44, 100
```